# Sum of attributes in NSSet

Tags: ios, swift

I have returned a `Customer` object from CoreData. I am trying to calculate the sum of all the `amount` attributes existing in an NSSet:

```
extension Customer {
    //...
    @NSManaged var customer_Invoices: NSSet?
}

extension Invoice {
    //...
    @NSManaged var amount: NSDecimalNumber?
    @NSManaged var invoice_Customer: Sale?
}
```

I could loop through each record and add them but I assume there is a better way?

What's the best way to do this? In C# I'd normally just use a simple `linq` query, does anything similar exist in Swift?

Comment: Have a look at the [Key-Value coding collection operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.htm). Something like `customer_Invoices.valueForKeyPath("@sum.amount")` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just loop.  It'll be easier for others to read and understand what you're doing.  And easier to debug, should you ever need to.  And it's probably the fastest (on the off chance that you're doing enough to matter).

If you really want to be clever you could do:

```
total = customer.valueForKeyPath("@sum.amount")
```

See [Key Value Coding / Collection Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE).  It's not as full-featured and powerful as LINQ so you will find it a poor substitute.  If you decide to use it, read the whole guide as there are some special things you might not expect about KVC.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to miss LINQ :(